# Change startup url in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I open Jupyter Notebook from the shell, it starts at "/home/nichlas/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-691-open.html" but I want it to start at "http://localhost:8888". I have honestly looked through all options in the config file and found nothing that worked - so how can I do this?

Answer (score 15):

- You have to generate the config file first by running the following command in terminal:

```bash
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

- Open this config file (`/home/yahya/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` on my system, for example).
- Find the parameter: `c.Notebook.use_redirect_file)`. *It is commented by default, and set to `True`*.
- Uncomment it and set it to `False`:

```py
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

Details about why this problem occurs can be found on this [Github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4353).

Comment: This requires Jupyter Notebook 6.0.2 or above. The commit where this feature was added: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/commit/a90957dae7d03d884af17894e72f7243d8d29157

Comment: If you install with `pip3 install jupyterlab`, the correct first command is `jupyter-notebook` (with a hyphen istead of a space)

Comment: Note this trick fixes https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4500

Comment: This is the correct solution for Firefox / Ubuntu 22.04. The reason this happen is because Firefox is installed as snap package and is thus ran in sandbox. It cannot access anything (including the access token set by Jupyter Notebook) outside the home directory.